# Function in sql server with table name as a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function

I want to write a function in sql server 2008 that can have table name as a variable.

eg:

```
create function test(@tbl varchar(50))

..

select * from @tbl

..
```

Comment: You will want to look at dynamic SQL, however you cannot use dynamic SQL inside of a function.

Comment: What do you want the function to do?  Why do you have tables that have exactly the same structure?  (Your example has `select *` implying that the columns are all the same.)

Comment: Since this could only work if all of the tables have the same shape (the number, names and types of columns returned from a function must be fixed), then presumably there's a limited number of such tables. In which case, you could just about do it with a massive `UNION ALL` structure and a `WHERE` clause on each, testing `@tbl`, such that they ensure that only one `SELECT` returns any rows. Also, table names should generally be declared as `sysname` rather than `varchar(50)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a SQL statement from a variable:

In function:

```
DECLARE @var AS VARCHAR(500)
SET @var = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tbl
EXECUTE (@var)
```

Comment: You can't called `EXECUTE` inside a function.